# How to take multiple shots with a timer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, camera

In the default camera app of my Samsung Galaxy S3, I can set the timer to take a picture after a delay of up to 10 sec.

I can also use the burst mode or the best photo mode to get several shots at once.

But I can't find the way to use the burst mode (or the best photo mode) with the timer.

So basically what I am looking for is:

1. I press the capture button
2. The count-down starts
3. The camera takes several shots (about 10 shots)

I have tried to use the voice control with the best photo mode, but it doesn't work when I am in a noisy place.

My phone is rooted and I don'y mind editing the core files

Comment: I've not tried it and it might not be easy, but long-press for specific time period can be performed using shell commands. If you can find a working way to long-press on the soft shutter button of your camera app to take photos in burst mode, then you can put those commands under a Tasker's task or some automation app's task or even in a simple shell script and bind them to some hardware button or to a gesture using apps. // Just an alternative, of course.

Comment: @Firelord, thanks ! I was looking for a simpler solution but apparently there isn't any.  I didn't know about shell script I will look into it!